# Recursive looping in Python to get Outlook folders

Tags: python, list, for-loop, recursion, outlook

I would like to list all the folders in Outlook, like:

```
xyz@abc.com\Inbox\Customers\Customer A
xyz@abc.com\Inbox\Customers\Customer B
xyz@abc.com\Inbox\Vendors\Vendor A
```

I found a code that works but I do not know how could I collect and concatenate the folders during the recursive call.

```
import codecs, win32com.client
    
def DumpFoldersRecursive(folders,indent):
    folder_paths = []
    for i in range(1,folders.Count+1):
        folder = folders[i]
        print(folder)
        DumpFoldersRecursive(folder.Folders,indent+1)

def DumpOutlookFolders():
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    DumpFoldersRecursive(o.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders,0)
    o = None

DumpOutlookFolders()
```

Could you please help how should I populate the folder_paths list.

Comment: You should either make your rec function return the contents so you can process the results or pass information on the current folder on to the the recursive call as paramters so the recursive call can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Exchangelib](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/).

It has many useful functions for what you are tyring to do but I guess you could just use the tree function which looks like this:

```
print(a.root.tree())
'''
root
├── inbox
│   └── todos
└── archive
    ├── Last Job
    ├── exchangelib issues
    └── Mom
'''
```

Comment: Thank you @Biorez. For the Exchangelib I should know the account password but for this project it is not given. That is why I need to find another approach.